# Install another DE on Ubuntu..?

Tags: unity

I can install another DE on ubuntu , so that the two desktops have separate programs ?

for example if I install kde on ubuntu and then I login with unity , I do not want to see the kde programs.

Is possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with notion of dual boot ?

Comment: No, the programs will be preserved.

Comment: Dual boot? Dafuq ahah